# Assemble IA-32 mov [bootdrv], dl

Tags: bootloader

I just start to program IA-32 assemble and boot loader and I can't understand one command: `mov [bootdrv], dl`.
dl is the low 8 bits of data register, but I dont know what is `[bootdrv]`. Is it a variable or something? How could a register be placed in [bootdrv]?

```
start:
    mov ax,0x7c0    ; BIOS puts us at 0:07C00h, so set DS accordinly
    mov ds,ax       ; Therefore, we don't have to add 07C00h to all our data

    mov [bootdrv], dl ; quickly save what drive we booted from
```

This is the beginning 3 line of a boot loader and `[bootdrv]` just appear without any definition, I couldn't understand.

Any information would be helpful and appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Yes, it's storing `dl` in a variable named `bootdrv`. Where did you get that code? If you copied it from somewhere you need to copy all the necessary code and not just parts of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[bootdrv]` is a specification of an absolute memory address. The code:

```
mov [bootdrv], dl
```

copies the contents of the 8-bit `DL` register into a byte in memory, at the address resulting of multiplying the current value of `DS` by `16`, then add the value `bootdrv`. `bootdrv` itself is a label, which a value that represents where in the current data segment is the memory position located.

On the other hand, the symbol `bootdrv` must be defined somewhere. Otherwise, the assembler will stop with a "*symbol not defined*" error. Maybe it's defined past the code (assemblers do two passes through the source code in order to get all symbols so they can be used even if they are defined after the code sequence that uses them). Maybe it's in a separate .INC file.

Comment: thanks a lot, that's helpful. another question is the content of register DL. I think I havenot write anything in it, so what will be contents?

Comment: The BIOS does. It contains the driver number used for booting: 0=floopy A, 1=floppy B,..., 80h=hard disk 1, 81h=hard disk 2, etc.

Comment: clear. great, thanks a lot. would you please recommand some tutorial for bootloader? I'm really struggling to learn it by myself.

Answer (score 0):

`mov [bootdrv], dl` indicates a segment:offset memory access. In the previous instruction, you configured the Data Segment register with an address, so the `mov [bootdrv], dl` instruction writes to the `segment:offset` address `0x7c0:bootdrv`, whatever bootdrv might be.